# Nikah without parent's knowing

Tags: nikah, parents, consent

Assalamualaikum, I've deeply fallen in love with a girl of my age, We live far away from each other and meet very rarely. It's been around 2 years and she loves me back and trusts me completely. I fear Allah (SWT) and I want to marry her to validate our relationship however our parents may not allow our nikah now since we're still studying. We hope that Insha'Allah they'll accept us after we have settled in our life. Is it possible for me to marry her without our parents knowing and then remarry her with their consent within 4-5 years Insha'Allah while refraining from sexual activities? If yes what is the valid islamic procedure?

Comment: What you are asking for is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engagement . As of the Islamic procedure, I don't know. Perhaps sharpen your question on this point or ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

وعليكم السلام ورحمة الله وبركاته

This is forbidden because the father of a girl must agree and it must be public, not secret, without other people knowing
Try to marry him with the knowledge of  family's